# Creating a general propositional formula given some condition

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

I'm trying to find a general propositional formula with $n$ number of variables where its models (the interpretation that satisfies the formula) are exactly those that satisfy an even number of atoms. Also, there is a condition where the formula contains only one occurrence of each atom.
e.g

$A \land B \land C$ is true only using the following interpretation

{$A \mapsto 1, B \mapsto 1, C \mapsto 0$}
{$A \mapsto 0, B \mapsto 1, C \mapsto 1$}
{$A \mapsto 1, B \mapsto 0, C \mapsto 1$}

because there is an even number of 1's.

The things I tried:

I tried building the formula using the truth table. However, if I did that I'll have more than an occurrence per atom.

Also, I tried a more desperate measure of using all variations of connectives (and, or, implies, and double implication only) but still no luck.

---

I think there will be two formulae for even or odd number of propositional variables, moreover, after searching the Web some places call this parity check formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $\leftrightarrow$ is associative, and thus we can generalize it to talke on any number of terms.  When you do so, you find that a generalized $\leftrightarrow$ is true iff an even number of its terms are false.

So, we can take:

$$\neg A \leftrightarrow \neg B \leftrightarrow \neg C$$

With $n$ atomic variables $P_1$ through $P_n$, you get:

$$\neg P_1 \leftrightarrow \neg P_2 \leftrightarrow ...  \leftrightarrow \neg P_n$$

Comment: That seems to work, thanks!. Can you explain how you were able to get to this formula, like what was your thought process

Comment: @Zed  I just knew that the generalized biconditional is true if and only if an even number of terms are false ... so I just had to negate the atomic variables. I guess (and maybe somewhat surprisingly) a good bit of logic is like that: just knowing a lot of logical principles can be more helpful than being able to logically reason things out form scratch!